# Running watir-webdriver on a server

Tags: amazon-web-services, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver, digital-ocean

I've been running watir-webdriver locally on my computer to auto submit some forms, but would like to move watir-webdriver from my local computer to a server somehow. I can't find any info of whether that is possible though.

How and where can you run watir-webdriver on a server online? Would you use AWS, Digital Ocean?

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely possible.

http://watirmelon.com/2011/08/29/running-your-watir-webdriver-tests-in-the-cloud-for-free/

The link is a few years old, but should at least be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've already seen it before, but it seemed a bit outdated and it seems like Watir is run in the "headless" setting. I am looking for something where I can log in to the server and Watir run on the actual browser.

Comment: If you do not want to run it headless, then you need a server with a head.